# Reconstruct signal from imprecise sampling?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to digitize a VGA signal with a low-power consumer computer running a consumer OS and am having issues with the stability of the sampling rate.

What I did so far:

- grabbing the green channel of the [VGA signal](http://martin.hinner.info/vga/timing.html) analogue signal
- converting it to a rectangular wave form (so either fully lit pixel
  or totally dark)
- sampling it with a computer and
- reconstructing the image

Here is an example of a screen I'm trying to capture (640x480x60hz)

[image]

And here is a [video of the capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qiil875gj5l484/video-capture.mp4?dl=0) my programme made.

The conversion to the rectangular wave loses most luminance information, but that is ok. The issue is that the sample rate is unstable because the sampling programme I wrote is interrupted by OS tasks for a few μs here and there. The timer resolution is also quite low (1 μs).

The image I'm trying to capture has a low rate of change, is mostly still for all practical purposes (so no motion video) and I can take multiple passes at each image.

Is there any way I can reconstruct the image information despite the unreliable sample rate?

edited for legibility

Comment: "sampling it with a computer": could you explain what that involves? What's the part doing the analog-to-digital conversion? How is that controlled from the computer?

Comment: The entire thing is an industrial computer - something like a laptop without a screen. The computer exposes digital pins (like a parallel printing port used in the 90s) which a programme can read. There are no other electronics involved apart from wires between the VGA port I'm trying to sample and the computer.

Comment: we'll need more infos about what these pins can do and how they can be controlled!

Comment: It would be instructive to have a example image of what you are capturing right now, and (if possible) a reference image of what the computer was generating. I am reminded of DIY projects 15 years ago where people were using the VGA output of their PC as an AM radio transmitter and others where they were eaves-dropping on the emitted radio energy of a VGA cable from a distance. I believe that someone used cheap USB tv receivers as software-defined radio front-ends?

Comment: If the source clock is stable, the image is mostly static and you are getting «dropouts» from OS interupt, perhaps you can sample many video frames, synchronize them and do some kind of averaging where missing pixels are left out from the average? I think that analog video contains explicit signals to synchronize frame start and line start, they should be visible on a generic sampled waveform.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was hoping to stay on the signal processing/algorithmic/math side of things :-) Since you asked: they are digital input pins, so they can distinguish between a low and a high input voltage but nothing more. I can read so far the vsync and hsync pulses and quantize the green channel.

Comment: @KnutInge edited original post with input image and output video,

Comment: Wow. That video looked ... challenging. Is it out of the question to use a commercial video grabber card?

Comment: @KnutInge it's a constrained, industrial setting. The video feed needs to go into _that_ specific computer which doesn't have any other interfaces than the digital pins.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgovassilis that's partially the info I need: It's really important to understand how you control when these pins are sampled. Who's in control of the sampling of these pins? Is it software, programming a hardware clock? Do you initiate each sample from in an interrupt service routine that you trigger based on a hardware? Is it just a loop that tries to initiate sampling as quickly as possible? (Honestly: You have practically no chance to recover from how broken this looks on the digital side. You need to get better about the timing of the sampling.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller the programme I wrote in C reads the pins which are memory-mapped into the process. The best timer I have access to is the system timer (resolution 1μs). There are two hardware interrupts triggered on vsync and hsync which I use to calibrate the timer, the rest is a tight loop that reads as fast as possible the quantized green signal and streams out its value together with the timer. As stated, the image is static - I was hoping to be able to exploit that to increase precision.

Comment: ah, so the memory-reading initializes the sampling! interesting.

Comment: So, really honest opinion: this would be far, far, far easier if your industrial PC had USB and you could just put a normal USB video frame grabber in a rugged box and connect it to that. The idea with using the fact the image is static is of course a very good one – but even if you went and from your video just averaged all your frames, would it look sensible?

Comment: @MarcusMüller as seen in the video, the image jumps around quite a lot, the jitter depends on the sampler's system load and network activity. Averaging or taking majority votes leaves no discernible details in the image.

Comment: yeah, and the problem is also that depending on when the dropouts happen, you might get some variation in both directions, so that even a "min hold" or something would be hard. Question: is there some way of knowing whether something interfered with the sampling (e.g. by comparing a CPU cycle counter to what it "should" be)

Comment: What kind of information do you need to know from the image? 640x480 pixels potentially containing anything? Or do you just need to distinguish between an up-pyramid and down-pyramid?

Comment: Do you have control over the image source (can you introduce some kind of pre-amble for unambigous synchronization?) or can you, like Marcus alluded to, log _when_ the sampling is being done (or not), thus being able to map the frame into «known» and «unknown» regions?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. @MarcusMüller I have access to the system timer and I can count the samples between "ticks". No guarantee that the sampling is uniform though.

Comment: @KnutInge the VGA spec talks about the "front porch" and "back porch" which are line markers. Again, not sure how to use them because of uneven sampling.

Comment: well, what about counting samples between ticks and throwing away any row where you have a mismatch from your expectation?